# Git - Suddenly asking for a password

Tags: git, github, repository, push, git-push

When I try to git push - It asks me for a password
the weird thing is that it works when I personal token that clearly appears on the same message that says enter password. I tried to remove .git and clone again but still asking for a password each time I push

Delete .git, repository and clone again

Comment: when you run **git push** statement, it means, you will push code on github, that's why you have to enter user/pass when you push. Do you know that?

Comment: Are you saying you are using a Personal Access Token (PAT), but git is still asking you for a password?

Comment: Yes, and I have been using PAT for months now and never asked me for a password ( which is the token ), this behavior started few days ago !